# The Reti endgame

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-chess

I'm trying to make my code in Python to solve correctly the Reti endgame by pushing Kh8 to Kg7, which is the only move leading to a draw for white. However the code given below  keeps saying

Positions searched: 0, Time: 0d 00h 00m 00s, RAM: 81.44 MB

Draw found in 5 move(s), time taken: 0d 00h 00m 00s.
Positions searched: 3433

But I wish to obtain the most accurate move by K. What line to touch ?

```
Initial board state:
. . . . . . . K
. . . . . . . .
k . P . . . . .
. . . . . . . p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 


Move Kh7:
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . K
k . P . . . . .
. . . . . . . p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 


Move Kb6:
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . K
. k P . . . . .
. . . . . . . p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 


Move Kh6:
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. k P . . . . K
. . . . . . . p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 


Move Kxc6:
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . k . . . . K
. . . . . . . p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 


Move Kxh5:
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . k . . . . .
. . . . . . . K
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
```

**The code in Python based on IDDFS**

```
import chess
import time
import threading
import sys
import os
import psutil

positions_searched = 0
stop_timer = False

def format_time(seconds):
    """Convert seconds to a format of %dd %hh %mm %ss."""
    days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
    hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return f"{int(days)}d {int(hours):02d}h {int(minutes):02d}m {int(seconds):02d}s"

def update_position_counter():
    """Periodically updates the counter of positions searched and prints RAM usage."""
    global stop_timer
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    start_time = time.time()
    while not stop_timer:
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        ram_usage = process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2  # Convert bytes to MB
        sys.stdout.write(f"\rPositions searched: {positions_searched}, Time: {format_time(elapsed_time)}, RAM: {ram_usage:.2f} MB\033[K")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    print()

def ddfs(board, depth, seeking_draw=False):
    global positions_searched
    positions_searched += 1

    if board.is_checkmate():
        return not seeking_draw, []
    
    if depth == 0 or board.is_game_over():
        # Consider draws excluding threefold repetition.
        return board.is_stalemate() or board.is_insufficient_material() or board.can_claim_fifty_moves(), []

    legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
    for move in legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        found_goal, goal_path = ddfs(board, depth - 1, seeking_draw)
        board.pop()
        if found_goal:
            return True, [move] + goal_path
    
    return False, []

def iterative_deepening_dfs(board, seeking_draw=False):
    global stop_timer
    depth = 0
    while True:
        found_goal, goal_sequence = ddfs(board.copy(), depth, seeking_draw)
        if found_goal:
            stop_timer = True
            return depth, goal_sequence
        depth += 1
        if depth > 15:
            stop_timer = True
            print(f"Search stopped at depth {depth}. No solution found.")
            break
    stop_timer = True
    return None, []

def print_move_sequence(original_board, move_sequence):
    """Prints the board state and moves leading to mate or draw."""
    print("\nInitial board state:")
    print(original_board, "\n")
    
    board = original_board.copy()
    for move in move_sequence:
        san_move = board.san(move)
        board.push(move)
        print(f"\nMove {san_move}:")
        print(board, "\n")

def main():
    initial_fen = "7K/8/k1P5/7p/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"
    board = chess.Board(initial_fen)

    stronger = 'black'
    seeking_draw = (stronger == 'black')

    stop_timer = False
    timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_position_counter)
    timer_thread.start()

    start_time = time.time()
    mate_depth, goal_sequence = iterative_deepening_dfs(board, seeking_draw)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    stop_timer = True
    timer_thread.join()

    outcome = "draw" if seeking_draw else "mate"
    print(f"\n{outcome.capitalize()} found in {mate_depth} move(s), time taken: {format_time(elapsed_time)}.")
    print(f"Positions searched: {positions_searched}")
    board.reset()
    board.set_fen(initial_fen)
    print_move_sequence(board, goal_sequence)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


    import chess
    import time
    import threading
    import sys
    import os
    import psutil
    
    positions_searched = 0
    stop_timer = False
    
    def format_time(seconds):
        """Convert seconds to a format of %dd %hh %mm %ss."""
        days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
        hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        return f"{int(days)}d {int(hours):02d}h {int(minutes):02d}m {int(seconds):02d}s"
    
    def update_position_counter():
        """Periodically updates the counter of positions searched and prints RAM usage."""
        global stop_timer
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        start_time = time.time()
        while not stop_timer:
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            ram_usage = process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2  # Convert bytes to MB
            sys.stdout.write(f"\rPositions searched: {positions_searched}, Time: {format_time(elapsed_time)}, RAM: {ram_usage:.2f} MB\033[K")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
        print()
    
    def ddfs(board, depth, seeking_draw=False):
        global positions_searched
        positions_searched += 1
    
        if board.is_checkmate():
            return not seeking_draw, []
        
        if depth == 0 or board.is_game_over():
            # Consider draws excluding threefold repetition.
            return board.is_stalemate() or board.is_insufficient_material() or board.can_claim_fifty_moves(), []
    
        legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
        for move in legal_moves:
            board.push(move)
            found_goal, goal_path = ddfs(board, depth - 1, seeking_draw)
            board.pop()
            if found_goal:
                return True, [move] + goal_path
        
        return False, []
    
    def iterative_deepening_dfs(board, seeking_draw=False):
        global stop_timer
        depth = 0
        while True:
            found_goal, goal_sequence = ddfs(board.copy(), depth, seeking_draw)
            if found_goal:
                stop_timer = True
                return depth, goal_sequence
            depth += 1
            if depth > 15:
                stop_timer = True
                print(f"Search stopped at depth {depth}. No solution found.")
                break
        stop_timer = True
        return None, []
    
    def print_move_sequence(original_board, move_sequence):
        """Prints the board state and moves leading to mate or draw."""
        print("\nInitial board state:")
        print(original_board, "\n")
        
        board = original_board.copy()
        for move in move_sequence:
            san_move = board.san(move)
            board.push(move)
            print(f"\nMove {san_move}:")
            print(board, "\n")
    
    def main():
        initial_fen = "7K/8/k1P5/7p/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"
        board = chess.Board(initial_fen)
    
        stronger = 'black'
        seeking_draw = (stronger == 'black')
    
        stop_timer = False
        timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_position_counter)
        timer_thread.start()
    
        start_time = time.time()
        mate_depth, goal_sequence = iterative_deepening_dfs(board, seeking_draw)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
        stop_timer = True
        timer_thread.join()
    
        outcome = "draw" if seeking_draw else "mate"
        print(f"\n{outcome.capitalize()} found in {mate_depth} move(s), time taken: {format_time(elapsed_time)}.")
        print(f"Positions searched: {positions_searched}")
        board.reset()
        board.set_fen(initial_fen)
        print_move_sequence(board, goal_sequence)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```